# Package failed to install, but does

Tags: software-center, 14.10

I have discovered something strange upon using Ubuntu 14.10. I have been using the OS for a week now and everything is running fine, but when I install or uninstall software from the software center, as well as when I install a system update, I get a error window saying: `Package Operation Failed`. But the operation seems to have worked fine? Everything I install works but that message pops up regardless. I'm just worried something is internally wrong with my system? Or am I worrying over nothing?

I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu 14.10 dual-boot with Windows 8.1 if that helps.

here is the details when error message pops up and output of `sudo apt-get upgrade`

when installing icedtea web plugin (what i chose for my example) http://pastebin.com/Btz7ws3p

when removing icedtea web plugin.
http://pastebin.com/WW3GykY8

output of sudo apt-get upgrade.
http://pastebin.com/THXmYyqf

Comment: Details will show who is the stopper. we need that log to help you

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade` in your question?  ([edit] it first)

Comment: added link in main post. didnt just paste in all the results as I wasn't sure whether it would be considered spammy.

Comment: basically what it is saying is that the open source java web plugin has failed to install properly.  It's the same error in all 3 pastes.  I might start by removing the offending java packages, and then starting over somehow, checking to see if java is working and if not, following a standard guide to install the java you want.